# Create a multiline plot with axes, labels, title, and legend using crops.csv file

Tags: python

Directions Load Data into pandas data frame Create variables for years, rice, wheat, maize, and soybean. Generate a plot that looks like below with fig size 8 by 6

```
 from google.colab import drive
 drive.mount(('/content/drive'), force_remount=True)
 url = '/content/drive/My_drive/crops.csv'

 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np 
 plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
 plt.plot()
 plt.title('Crops')
 plt.xlabel('number of years')
 plt.ylabel('number of crops')
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do i add the variables for this coding problem